# How to animate the underlining of Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, flutter-animation

How should I begin to approach this particualr UI requirement? Animating the `Text` doesn't help.
What would be a good approach to do this in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a Container() Widget right under the text and give it a height of 1. Then you can change the width of the Container from 0 to what you wish.